# What is the best way to run more than one Jmeter Scripts at once?

Tags: jmeter

I created 7 individual Jmeter Scripts which runs properly. I need to run them at once by different numbers of threads/users. Hence I merged them in one Test Plan with 7 different Thread Groups which also run properly without any issue.

But as because all the Scripts/Thread Groups runs at once, the .JTL file captures the results as they run. The order of execution of the Jmeter Samplers differs on 2nd, 3rd run, and so on.

Hence, it's difficult to organise the results manully and compare them in excel sheet.

Although there is an option on Test Plan interface i.e. "Run Thread Groups consecutively" which run the Thread Group one by one, where the results will be captured sequentially. But I do not wish to do like this way, I want to run all the Thread Groups at once with different sets of threads/users.

Please, guide me on this.

**Note:** I'm running the test through Non-GUI mode on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just name your Thread Groups differently

[image: Different Thread Group Names]

Your results file will contain different thread names so you will be able to distinguish request originated from the different thread groups:

[image: Results file]

If you don't see thread group names in .jtl results file, just add `jmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true` line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation) or pass it as a command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.thread_name=true -n -t example.jmx -l example.jtl
```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for comprehensive information on JMeter Properties domain.

---

Another option could be adding [Simple Data Writer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Simple_Data_Writer) listener to each thread group and configure it to store results in different files like:

[image: Simple Data Writer]

Comment: The 2nd option (Simple Data Writer) is appropriate to my case, Thanks